# Updating in SQL Problems

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me with this problem? I'm trying to update my database using the SQL below, but when I run it this message comes out:

> The multi-part identifier "try_subject.subject_code" could not be bound.

```
UPDATE try_schoolyear 
SET school_year= '" & drpcurriculumyear.SelectedItem.Text & "' 
FROM try_schoolyear
INNER JOIN try_yearlvl on  
    try_schoolyear.schoolyearID=try_yearlvl.schoolyearId 
WHERE try_subject.subject_code= '" & txtsearchcourse.Text & "'
```

Answer (score 1):

the table `try_subject` won't be joined in your query. And that is why the engine can't find it.

Comment: Sure. How is your table structure? And what are the related keys?